# dnx holding locks on files IIS - unable to copy over

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, dnx, file-locking

We have an ASPNet5 site (angular site and webapi service) running under IIS 8.5 successfully.  The issue we have now run into is dnx holding locks on files that prevent us from re-deploying the site from our automated deployment server.  The task is simply using robocopy to perform the task but I can reproduce with a simple copy as well.  Essentially, the error is "process cannot access the file xxxx because it is being used".  The files in question are mostly under the approot/packages dir.

The question is how to work around this.  The main goal being able to re-deploy without having to bring down the site which seems impractical.

We are running on Win2012R2, IIS8.5 and clr rc1-update1.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you find a work around for this in the end? Killing the dnx.exe process releases the locks but I've got multiple asp.net core web apps so I don't know which is which and don't want to nuke them all every time I push an update to one... Hmmm.

Comment: DNX is deprecated, .NET Core CLI should be used, so voting  to close as a problem, that cannot be reproduced.